# Tracking down bottleneck/bug generating tilemap in html5 canvas game in firefox

Tags: performance, html, firefox

I'm using a tile engine to generate huge maps based off an array. The map is divided into zones, only tiles in zones around the "view" are drawn which gives great performance on giant maps and smooth movement.

However, I've hit a limit only with Firefox that I cannot figure out.

At first I thought it was just because I'm using giant arrays, firefox is able to handle 100x100 64px square tiles without error, but anything above that gives a "stop script" error and locks up FF.

At the same time, IE, Chrome, Safari, and even my 2.5 year old HTC android phone can generate maps 500x300+ tiles (though the phone only runs at 4fps but it at least makes it through the initialization + draws the map, unlike Firefox on my desktop pc!!)!!!!!! Which is 150,000 tiles !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Compared to Firefox choking at 10,000 tiles....how can my 2.5 year old phone generate maps 15x+ larger than firefox running on my desktop?????

In resource monitor my CPU and RAM max immediately in FF then give the "close document to prevent data loss" error...but my phone can handle much larger maps than my desktop which makes me believe there's a bug with how FF handles loops compared to IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and my phone which handle much larger loops???

Here's the version that works in all browsers including FF http://simplehotkey.com/TileEngine/tiles/main.html with a 100x100 tile map

Here's a version with a 500x100 tile map (50,000 tiles) that chokes FF but runs on all the other browsers and at least loads on my phone: http://simplehotkey.com/Tiles/main.html

Anyone have an explanation why an older phone would generate the map 15x larger than FF can handle on my desktop????????

Answer (score 0):

Are all 150,000 tiles being shown at once?  Or are they just loaded but not used until needed?

64px square decoded images use 16KB of RAM each.  So 10,000 of them would use 160MB of RAM.  150,000 tiles would use 2+GB of RAM.  And what I see here is Firefox using up a lot of RAM so that it starts swapping....

Comment: I think there is no 150 000 unique images to load. That mean that Firefox creates all of them itself. And this is the reason why only FF swaps.

Comment: Well, are the tiles images to start with?  How are they created?